# formatting <div> <td> inside table

Tags: html, css

Here is my page structure with three column: 30-40-30

Here is fiddle:  http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/BDfhJ

Proble is : 
I want to position `div` in  right section at particular height with div-height is 200px.

When I put `style="height:150px"` in right section div, right div remains on top and left and middle section move at 150px height.

Why?

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:30%">
            <div class="left">
            Hi
            </div>
       </td>
            <td style="width:40%">
              <div class="middle"> 
                            <input type="text" id="url" width="80%">    
                            <button type="submit" onclick="GetSentiment()" value="Submit">GetSentiment</button>
               </div>
            </td>

            <td style="width:30%">
            <div class="right" style="height:150px">
                      nice

            </div>
            </td>

    </tr>

            </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the text in the `<td>` elements is vertically centered by default.  If you apply styles to the `<div>`s in the other `<td>` elements, they will also behave.  Alternatively, you can do `<td valign="top"...>` for each `<td>`.

**EDIT:** I notice that the code you posted above is *much* simpler than the code you posted on github.  There may be other factors, including JavaScript or other styles affecting your production code.  Without the production HTML, CSS, and scripts, it's impossible to determine everything that could be affecting the layout.

Comment: thanks, I tested your suggestion. In fiddle it works but when I tested in my actual page problme still persist:

Comment: Please post a link to an actual page, not just the source.  Also, what changes did you make, and what problems are you still having?

Comment: I am testing on localhost. I assigned `valign="top"` to each `td` on the link above at line: 157, 177, 233. Problem is same I have given in my main question.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from that gist what the problem is, because the markup will not fully load in a fiddle.  A simplified version works just fine (http://jsfiddle.net/t5Gxk/). Try posting a fiddle of the HTML content of your page.  Also, you should know that the `<!-- <?php include 'logout.php'; ?> -->` in your code *will* call logout.php; the comment tags don't prevent the PHP from executing.